# Quick and easy java program to talk to JIRA and create epics, stories and issues

Tags: java, rest, jira

I am looking for some quick and easy java program that would interface with JIRA and create epics, stories and issues

Comment: This question is considered to be unsuitable for this site since it asks us to find an external resource or to code the entire program as an answer. In the former case, these answers are opinion-based. In the latter, they are not reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this program can be modified/expanded and could be optimized. I am looking for feedback. I am planning to add XML file in which one can add all the data and can in turn create task, epics, stories etc.

```
package com.xxxxxx.mavenify.HelloWorldy;

/**/
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.apache.commons.io.Charsets;
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;


import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;


/**
 * Hello world!a
 *
 */
public class App 
{public static String ticket = "https://wts-jira.xxxxx.com/jira/rest/api/2/issue"; //rest/api/2/issue/

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        getHashmap();
    }

    public static String encodedPassword()
    {       return "Basic dT zU3NjI3MjpTdW1tZXIyMDE5";                  
    }

    public static String generateEpic(String summary,String componentIdNumber,String componentIdText,String applicationIDNumber,
            String applicationIDText,String acceptanceCriteria1, String dueDate,String descriptionText,String issueType)
    {
        return new String("{\"fields\": {\"project\": {\"key\": \"WHSAR\"},\"assignee\": {\"name\":\"u576272\"},\"summary\": \""+ applicationIDText + " - Artifactory migration"+ "\",\r\n" + 
                "\"customfield_12703\": \"" + applicationIDText + "\", \"customfield_19545\": {\"Option id\": \"38679\",\"value\": \"Artifactory migration\"\r\n" + 
                "},\"customfield_10183\": 7,\"customfield_15891\": {\"Option id\": \""+ applicationIDNumber+ "\",\"value\": \""+ applicationIDText+"\"},"
                        + "\"customfield_11709\": \"Receive sign-off email or message from the app team manager.\",\"duedate\": \"26-04-19\",\r\n" + 
                "\"description\": \""+descriptionText+"\", \"issuetype\": {\"name\": \"Epic\"}}}\r\n"); 
        }

    public static String generateUserStory(String summary,String componentIdNumber,String componentIdText,String applicationIDNumber,
            String applicationIDText,String acceptanceCriteria1,String dueDate,String descriptionText,String issueType, String epicLink)
    {                                           
        return new String("{\"fields\": {\"project\": {\"key\": \"WHSAR\" }, \"summary\": \"" + summary + "\", \"customfield_19545\": { \"Option id\": \""+componentIdNumber+"\",\"value\": \""+componentIdText+"\"}, \"customfield_15891\": {\r\n" + 
                "\"Option id\": \""+applicationIDNumber+"\",\"value\": \""+applicationIDText+"\"},\"duedate\": \"" + dueDate +"\",\"customfield_12702\":\""+epicLink+"\", \"description\": \""+ applicationIDText + " - "+ "Ensure artifactory migration is complete.\","
                        + "\"customfield_11709\": \""+acceptanceCriteria1+"\",\"issuetype\": {\"name\": \"User Story\" }}}");
    }

    public static String generateTask(String summary,String componentIdNumber,String componentIdText,String applicationIDNumber,
            String applicationIDText,String acceptanceCriteria1,String dueDate,String descriptionText,String issueType, String storyLink)
    {
        return new String("{\"fields\": {\"project\": { \"key\": \"WHSAR\" },\"parent\": {\"key\": \""+ storyLink +"\"},"
                + "\"customfield_15891\": {\"Option id\": \""+applicationIDNumber+"\",\"value\": \""+applicationIDText+"\" },\"summary\": \"" + applicationIDText +" -  "+ summary
                + "\",\"customfield_19545\": {\"Option id\": \""+componentIdNumber+"\",\"value\": \""+componentIdText+"\"},"
                + "\"customfield_11709\": \""+acceptanceCriteria1+ "\",\"duedate\": \"26-04-19\",\"description\": \"" + applicationIDText + " -  "+ descriptionText + "\",\"issuetype\": {\"id\": \"5\"}}}");
    }

    public static void getHashmap() 
    {        
        try {
            String applicationIDNumber = "38782";


/*          38717 = IBOSS               
*/                          
            String applicationIDText = "1SOR";
            String dueDate = "06-05-19";    
            org.json.simple.JSONObject jnew;            
            String issueType;
            JSONParser j1 = new JSONParser();

            org.json.simple.JSONObject jnew2;
            org.json.simple.JSONObject jnew3;

            jnew = genEpic(applicationIDNumber, applicationIDText, dueDate);

            String summaryUS1 = applicationIDText  + " - Ensure project kick off date and resource details from app manager.";
            String summaryUS2 = applicationIDText + " - Ensure migration pre-requisites and Go/no go.";
            String summaryUS3 = applicationIDText + " - Ensure artifactory migration is complete.";

            String componentIdNoUS1 = "38680";
            String componentIdTextUS1 ="Prerequisites";

            String accepatanceCriteriaUS1 = "Acceptance of Project kick off date and the resources details from app manager.";
            String accepatanceCriteriaUS2 = "Migration pre-requisites are complete and team decision of either Go /no go.";
            String accepatanceCriteriaUS3 = "Receive sign-off email or message from the app team manager.";         

            String descriptionUS1 = "Ensure app manager has confirmed project kick off date and resource details for the application being migrated.";
            String descriptionUS2 = "Ensure migration pre-requisites are complete before the application migration has started and team is clear on Go/no go.";
            String descriptionUS3 = "Ensure artifactory migration is complete.";

            String componentIdNoUS2  = "38682"; 
            String componentIdTextUS2 ="Initiation";

            String componentIdNoUS3  = "38681";
            String componentIdTextUS3 ="Verification";          

            issueType ="user story";
            String epicLink =jnew.values().toArray()[2].toString();         

            org.json.simple.JSONObject jnew1 =  (org.json.simple.JSONObject)j1.parse(genIssue(summaryUS1, applicationIDNumber, applicationIDText, componentIdNoUS1, 
                    componentIdTextUS1, accepatanceCriteriaUS1, dueDate, descriptionUS1, issueType, epicLink, ""));

            System.out.println("story 1 done ->" +jnew1.values().toArray()[2].toString());

            j1= new JSONParser();
            jnew2 =  (org.json.simple.JSONObject)j1.parse(genIssue(summaryUS2, applicationIDNumber, applicationIDText, componentIdNoUS2, 
                    componentIdTextUS2, accepatanceCriteriaUS2, dueDate, descriptionUS2, issueType, epicLink, ""));

            System.out.println("story 2 done ->" +jnew2.values().toArray()[2].toString());

            j1= new JSONParser();
            jnew3 =  (org.json.simple.JSONObject)j1.parse(genIssue(summaryUS3, applicationIDNumber, applicationIDText, componentIdNoUS3, 
                    componentIdTextUS3, accepatanceCriteriaUS3, dueDate, descriptionUS3, issueType, epicLink, ""));

            System.out.println("story 3 done ->" + jnew3.values().toArray()[2].toString());

            genTask(applicationIDNumber, applicationIDText, dueDate, jnew2.values().toArray()[2].toString(), jnew3.values().toArray()[2].toString());


        }catch (Exception ex) {

            //handle exception here
            System.out.println(ex.toString() +  " \n "+ ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            //Deprecated
            //httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); 
        }       
    }

    static org.json.simple.JSONObject genEpic(String applicationIDNumber, String applicationIDText, String dueDate)
            throws ParseException, IOException {
        org.json.simple.JSONObject jnew;
        String summaryEText = applicationIDText  + " - Artifactory migration"; //1CCP
        String componentIdNumber = "38679";
        String componentIdText = "Artifactory migration";           
        String acceptanceCriteria = "Client Sign-off";

        String descriptionText = applicationIDText  + " - Below instructions are applicable to you or your team ONLY if you use "
                + "old artifactory instance https://wfs-artifactory.xxxxx.com. \\n It is moved to new instance - "
                + "https://artifactory-intg-b.xxxxxx.net ";     

        String issueType ="epic";

        JSONParser j = new JSONParser();
        jnew =  (org.json.simple.JSONObject)j.parse(genIssue(summaryEText, applicationIDNumber, applicationIDText, componentIdNumber, 
                componentIdText, acceptanceCriteria, dueDate, descriptionText, issueType, "", ""));

        //{"customfield_15891":"Option id 'null' is not valid"}
        System.out.println("epic done " + applicationIDText + " -> " + jnew.values().toArray()[2].toString());
        return jnew;
    }

    static void genTask(String applicationIDNumber, String applicationIDText, String dueDate, 
            String storyLink2, String storyLink3) throws ParseException, IOException {
        String issueType;
        String summaryT1 = "Ensure dev-lead acceptance of migration documentation";
        String componentIdT1 = "38684";
        String componentTextT1 = "Documentation";
        //appID and text
        String acceptanceCriteriaT1 = "Confirmation from the dev-lead that migration document is received.";
        String descriptionT1 ="Ensure dev-lead has received the migration documentation.";

        String summaryT2 = "Identify application dependencies.";
        String componentIdT2 = "38679";
        String componentTextT2 = "Artifactory migration";
        //appID and text
        String acceptanceCriteriaT2 = "Document application dependencies in the sub-task:";
        String descriptionT2 ="Identify application dependencies - set of questionnaire \\n " +
                "1. if job touches AHP, MAVEN, Gradle, nuget, npm, promethus, nexus.\\n " + 
                "2. If other applications are dependent on application in scope - if so how many of them and what are they? \\n ";


        String summaryT3 = "Ensure successful local build";
        String componentIdT3 = "38683";
        String componentTextT3 = "CI (Continuous Integration)";
        //appID and text
        String acceptanceCriteriaT3 = "email or message from SME or app team that local builds are successful";
        String descriptionT3 ="Ensure successful local build.  Here is the documentation:"
                + "https://confluence.xxxxx.net/display/WBT/Gradle+User+Set+Up+for+using+INTG \\n "  
                                + "https://confluence.xxxxxx.net/display/WBT/Maven+User+Set+Up+for+using+INTG \\n"  
                                + "https://confluence.xxxxxxx.net/display/WBT/Nuget+User+Set+Up+for+using+INTG \\n"  
                                + "https://confluence.xxxxxxx.net/display/WBT/NPM+User+Set+Up+for+using+INTG";

        String summaryT4 = "Ensure successful build from jenkin job";
        String componentIdT4 = "38683";
        String componentTextT4 = "CI (Continuous Integration)";
        //appID and text
        String acceptanceCriteriaT4 = "Receive sign-off or message from app team that jenkins builds are good.";
        String descriptionT4 ="Ensure successful build from jenkin job.";

        issueType ="task";

        JSONParser j1 = new JSONParser();
        System.out.println("sub task 1 done ->" + ((org.json.simple.JSONObject)j1.parse(genIssue(summaryT1, applicationIDNumber, applicationIDText, 
                componentIdT1,componentTextT1, acceptanceCriteriaT1, dueDate, descriptionT1, issueType, "", storyLink2))).values().toArray()[2].toString());

        j1= new JSONParser();

        System.out.println("sub task 2 done ->" + ((org.json.simple.JSONObject)j1.parse(genIssue(summaryT2, applicationIDNumber, applicationIDText, 
                componentIdT2,componentTextT2, acceptanceCriteriaT2, dueDate, descriptionT2, issueType, "", storyLink2))).values().toArray()[2].toString());

        j1= new JSONParser();

        System.out.println("sub task 3 done ->" + ((org.json.simple.JSONObject)j1.parse(genIssue(summaryT3, applicationIDNumber, applicationIDText, 
                componentIdT3,componentTextT3, acceptanceCriteriaT3, dueDate, descriptionT3, issueType, "", storyLink3))).values().toArray()[2].toString());

        j1= new JSONParser();

        System.out.println("sub task 4 done ->" + ((org.json.simple.JSONObject)j1.parse(genIssue(summaryT4, applicationIDNumber, applicationIDText, 
                componentIdT4,componentTextT4, acceptanceCriteriaT4, dueDate, descriptionT4, issueType, "", storyLink3))).values().toArray()[2].toString());
    }

    static String genIssue(String summary, String applicationIDNumber, String applicationIDText, String componentIdNumber,
            String componentIdText, String acceptanceCriteria,String dueDate, String descriptionText, String issueType, String epicLink,String storyLink) 
            throws IOException {

        String jsonString = "";
        if(issueType == "epic")
            jsonString = generateEpic(summary,componentIdNumber,componentIdText,applicationIDNumber,
                    applicationIDText,acceptanceCriteria,dueDate,descriptionText, issueType);
        else if(issueType =="user story")
            jsonString = generateUserStory(summary, componentIdNumber, componentIdText, applicationIDNumber, 
                    applicationIDText,acceptanceCriteria, dueDate, descriptionText, issueType, epicLink);
        else if(issueType == "task")
            jsonString = generateTask(summary, componentIdNumber, componentIdText, applicationIDNumber, 
                    applicationIDText,acceptanceCriteria, dueDate, descriptionText, issueType, storyLink);


        OkHttpClient client1 = new OkHttpClient();

        MediaType mediaType1 = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body1 = RequestBody.create(mediaType1,jsonString);
        Request request1 = new Request.Builder()
          .url("https://wts-jira.xxxxxx.com/rest/api/2/issue")
          .post(body1)
          .addHeader("Authorization", "Basic dTU3NjI3MjpTdW1tZXIyMDE5")
          .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
          .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")             
          .build();

        Response response1 = client1.newCall(request1).execute();
        return response1.body().string();
    }   
}
```

Here is the POM.XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.xxxxxx.mavenify</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloWorldy</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>HelloWorldy</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```